# Google Maps Flutter: How to place multiple markers from firebase RTDB

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get multiple markers from firebase RTDB using the "getAllDriversLocation()" method and place them on the map. The coordinates may or may not be changing every few seconds, so this change has to automatically reflect on the map.

I want to get all the markers inside the node "Driver Coordinates". Inside this node there are randomID's, each ID represents a different driver.

Database structure: "users" > "Driver Coordinates" > "randomID"

[image: A picture of what my firebase RTDB looks like]

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String idScreen = "MainScreen";

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
 
  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(39.04475400135195, 125.75316892920314),
    // target: LatLng(4.0435, 39.6682),
    zoom: 18.0,
    tilt: 70,
  );

  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    // This method grabs user location and streams updates of location to the database
    try {
      // Uint8List imageData = await getMarker();
      var position = await _locationTracker.getLocation();
      currentCoordinates.add(position.latitude);
      currentCoordinates.add(position.longitude);
      // goTOCurrentUserLocation();
      // final randomUserUid = await getParentUID();
      if (_locationSubscription != null) {
        _locationSubscription.cancel();
      }
      _locationSubscription = _locationTracker.onLocationChanged.listen(
        (newLocalData) {
          if (_controllerGoogleMaps != null) {
            setState(() {
              currentLatForAdress = newLocalData.latitude;
              currentLongForAdress = newLocalData.longitude;
            });
          }
        },
      );
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
        debugPrint("Permission Denied");
      }
    }
  }

  logOut() async {
    // Navigator.of(context).pop();
    auth.signOut();
  }

  Future<void> startForegroundService() async {
    // ignore: await_only_futures
    await ForegroundService().start();
  }

  Future getAllDriversLocation() async {
   
    databaseReference
        .child("users")
        // .child(schlNameUpperCae)
        .child("Driver Coordinates")
        .onValue
        .listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        var value = event.snapshot.value;
        var valueToString = value["latitude"].toString();
        print(value.toString());
        print(valueToString);
        driversLocation = Map.from(value)
            .values
            .map((e) => LocationCoordinates.fromJson(Map.from(e)))
            .toList();
        print(driversLocation);
        print(driversLocation);
      });
    });
    // setState(() {
    //   _markers.add(
    //     Marker(
    //       markerId: MarkerId(driversName),
    //       position: locaitonDetails,
    //       infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "$driverName"),
    //       icon: pinLocationIcon,
    //     ),
    //   );
    // }
    return driversLocation;
  }

  void addMarker(loc, index) {
    //Making this markerId dynamic
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId('Marker $index');

    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position: LatLng(loc.latitude, loc.longitude),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'test'),
    );

    setState(() {
      // adding a new marker to map
      markers[markerId] = marker;
      //print(marker);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (_locationSubscription != null) {
      _locationSubscription.cancel();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentLocation();
    BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
            'assets/images/customPIN.png')
        .then(
      (onValue) {
        pinLocationIcon = onValue;
      },
    );
    getAllDriversLocation();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        elevation: 0,
        toolbarHeight: 50,
        // shadowColor: Colors.grey,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Multiple Moving Markers",
              style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GoogleMap(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
            // padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 100, 0, 15) + MediaQuery.of(context).padding,
            markers: _markers,
            trafficEnabled: true,
            compassEnabled: false,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
            zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
            zoomControlsEnabled: false,
            initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
            mapType: _mapType == null ? MapType.normal : _mapType,
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
              controller.setMapStyle(Utils.mapStyles);
              _controllerGoogleMaps.complete(controller);
              newGoogleMapController = controller;
              // startForegroundService();
              // goTOCurrentUserLocation();
              // getCurrentLocation();
              getAllDriversLocation();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
 
class LocationCoordinates {
  final double latitude;
  final double longitude;
  final String name;

  LocationCoordinates({
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.name,
  });

  static LocationCoordinates fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return LocationCoordinates(
        latitude: json["latitude"],
        longitude: json["latitude"],
        name: json["DriverUID"]);
  }
}

displayToastMessage(String message, BuildContext context) {
  // create the displayToastMessage method.
  // giveit a parameter that will be a message.
  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: (message));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the `driverLocation` `Map` into the `_markers` list when the realtime database listener is called.

```dart
void getAllDriversLocation() {
   
    databaseReference
        .child("users")
        // .child(schlNameUpperCae)
        .child("Driver Coordinates")
        .onValue
        .listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        ...
        driversLocation = Map.from(value)
            .values
            .map((e) => LocationCoordinates.fromJson(Map.from(e)))
            .toList();
        ...
        _markers = driversLocation.map((location) {
            final int index = driversLocation.values.indexOf(location);
            final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId('Marker $index');

            return Marker(
                markerId: markerId
                position: LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude),
            );
        }).toList();


      });
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this and a similar method too. I get the following exception; 

"The getter 'values' isn't defined for the type 'List<dynamic>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'values', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'values'."

Comment: Check out the updated answer.